# Codemagic flutter failed to build android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, codemagic

Whenever I run it it get stuck in android. This happened to me locally and I solve it doing flutter clean, which I don't know how to do in codemagic. The problem is that is nos building, heres the log.

```
 Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                          


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\\Users\\thech\\Downloads\\nueva_temporada-20210514T040146Z-001\\nueva_temporada\\build\\app\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\AssetManifest.json



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 30s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             31.3s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Build failed :|
Failed to build for Android
```

Comment: You can try adding flutter clean in Post-clone script, in code magic.

Comment: How you do this? Sorry I'm new to codemagic

Answer (score 0):

any chance you have hardcoded path in your build.gradle or somewhere else? `C:\\Users` is not a valid path on Codemagic builder machines because it uses macOS or Linux

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't appear that, no idea why is appearing. So I was working on Visual Studio Code. I pushed everything into a new branch to GitHub, then I used what I committed in the branch to codemagic. It works fine in VS Code but not in codemagic.