# CODEMAGIC is using path from windows

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, codemagic

so basically when I run my project in codemagic it uses the path of your packages from windows and it result on this error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\\Users\\thech\\Downloads\\nueva_temporada-20210514T040146Z-001\\nueva_temporada\\build\\app\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\AssetManifest.json
```

So I was working on Visual Studio Code. I pushed everything into a new branch to GitHub, then I used what I committed in the branch to codemagic. It works fine in VS Code but not in codemagic since Codemagic uses MacOS or Linux. To solve this you would need to use **Flutter Clean** but I can't run commands like this in Codemagic.

Full log:

```
    == Building for Android ==

> flutter build apk --debug

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                          


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\\Users\\thech\\Downloads\\nueva_temporada-20210514T040146Z-001\\nueva_temporada\\build\\app\\intermediates\\flutter\\debug\\flutter_assets\\AssetManifest.json



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 30s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             32.5s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Build failed :|
Failed to build for Android

Building iOS
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codemagic flutter failed to build android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67530927/codemagic-flutter-failed-to-build-android)

Comment: No @MikhailTokarev because I still can't or don't know how to remove the path from windows.